# How to address C4191 warning around calls to GetProcAddress with FARPROC?

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, function-pointers, compiler-warnings

Recently I tried to use [/Wall Visual C++ option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y(VS.71).aspx) to enable all warnings and found that the following code:

```
typedef BOOL ( WINAPI * TIsWow64ProcessFunction )( HANDLE, BOOL* );
TIsWow64ProcessFunction isWow64ProcessFunction = reinterpret_cast<TIsWow64ProcessFunction> (
    ::GetProcAddress( kernel32DllHandle, "IsWow64Process" ) );
```

spawned [C4191](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0eaaaf7(VS.80).aspx):

```
warning C4191: 'reinterpret_cast' : unsafe conversion from 'FARPROC' to 'TIsWow64ProcessFunction'
Calling this function through the result pointer may cause your program to fail
```

If I use a C-style cast the same warning appears but now it mentions "type cast" instead of "reinterpret_cast".

The same warning is repeated for just any case I call `GetProcAddress()` and convert its return value to some usable function pointer.

How do I address these warnings? Do I need to make alterations to my code?

Comment: #pragma warning(disable:4191) seems appropriate if the goal is to reach 0 warnings: This particular warning is useless as theres no (apparent) way to avoid it while keeping the functionality.

Comment: Does it fire a warning for you? I never used /wall, only P4 warning level in VS.

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *DISABLEREDIR) (PVOID*); 
DISABLEREDIR fpnDisableRedir = NULL;
fpnDisableRedir = (DISABLEREDIR)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");

Comment: @Kra: Yes, it spawns C4191 with /Wall. The key is C4191 is disabled by default and /Wall enables it.

Comment: interesting, one more warning to ignore as I see it :)

Comment: @Kra - you might consider adding the following security related warnings under Microsoft compilers: `pragma warning(once: 4191 4242 4263 4264 4266 4302 4826 4905 4906 4928)`. Also see [“Off By Default” Compiler Warnings in Visual C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c.aspx) on Microsoft's blog.

Comment: I believe @Cody's answer below is the correct solution here. There' no need to disable warnings and use pragmas. The only thing that is needed is casting `GetProcAddress` to a `VOIDP` or `void*`. Then, you can cast to anything you want, like `TIsWow64ProcessFunction`. For completeness, Clang requires this hack on occasion, too. Its not limited to MS compilers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are casting a FARPROC (function pointer with no args) to a function pointer with args.  Normally this is a hugely dumb thing to do that will probably result in stack corruption.

Now it turns out that GetProcAddress() doesn't really return a FARPROC and you do actually know what you're doing -- but the compiler doesn't know that and it feels obliged to warn you.

The only way you can silence it is using a #pragma or a compiler switch to turn off the warning.  It is ugly and messy, but that is Windows programming for you.  :-)

Comment: dlsym returns a void pointer so I don't think the compiler would give a warning.  It assumes that a void * is as big as a function pointer.  I don't know if that is always true.  I don't think the standard guarantees it.

Comment: VS 2010 reports it as an error. #pragma is not helping resolve the issue.

Comment: article http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/importexportissues/article.php/c123/Explicitly-Linking-to-Classes-in-DLLs.htm discuss this problem, but it is not very clear to me. Anyone please explain.

Comment: Hi Ajay  The codeguru article is about exporting class member functions, which is more complex.  Is that what you're doing?  Try to write a very short program that shows the error and post it on stackoverflow.  I probably need to see the code to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 14):

As other answers have already mentioned, this is a useful warning. [*Normally*, this type of coercion would be a serious bug hiding in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215425/366904).

Therefore, you probably don't want to disable it globally with a compiler switch. Yet you still need to call `GetProcAddress`, and you like your builds to compile cleanly without warnings.

You have two good options:

1. **Suppress each individual warning using an MSVC-specific pragma.** In a new line just above the maligned cast, add the following code:

   ```
   #pragma warning(suppress: 4191)
   ```

   This suppresses the warning for the very next line of code *only*, ensuring that it is not globally suppressed and you'll still get a warning if you try to do something stupid elsewhere in the code base. Of course, you'll need to add this each time you use `GetProcAddress`, which is kind of a pain. Worse yet, it's a non-portable, MSVC-specific extension that uglifies your code.

   So, alternatively…
2. You can silence the warning by **explicitly casting the result of `GetProcAddress`** (a `FARPROC`) **to `void*`**, and then casting that `void*` to the specific function-pointer type. For example:

   ```
   typedef BOOL ( __stdcall *TIsWow64ProcessFunction )( HANDLE, BOOL* );

   TIsWow64ProcessFunction isWow64ProcessFunction =
       reinterpret_cast<TIsWow64ProcessFunction>(
          reinterpret_cast<void*>(
          ::GetProcAddress(hInstance, "IsWow64Process")));
   ```

   This approach will work with other compilers, is slightly less ugly, and is arguably more semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the compiler cannot guarantee that the function is of the appropriate type, so it's unsafe for you to call the resulting pointer. However, in a VS program you don't have to link or load against the Windows .dlls explicitly, they will be loaded for you and any function in the Windows header is always available to use.

Comment: Suppose I really ned to dynamically load a library. What do I do with the warning? Do I ignore it? Does the warning just mean that it's up to me to be sure that the function actually has the right signature in the implementations?

Comment: @sharptooth: Basically, yes. The only solution to this problem is static loading of a DLL- which is what occurs with Windows headers.

Comment: @Puppy - You can cast the result of `GetprocAddress` to a `void*`. That will squash the C4191 warning. Then, cast it to the function pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

I was bothered also by these warnings as I use this sort of thing quite often. I liked @Cody Gray's answer as it suppresses the warning only at the point of use but doesn't filter out other possibly valid warnings.

I made a simple function_cast helper to make it a bit more c++ like:

```
template<typename Result, typename Original>
Result function_cast(Original fptr)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<Result>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(fptr));
}
```

The OP's code becomes:

```
auto isWow64ProcessFunction = function_cast<TIsWow64ProcessFunction>(::GetProcAddress( kernel32DllHandle, "IsWow64Process" ) );
```

Comment: casting function pointer to `void *` is illegal, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645660/why-cant-i-cast-a-function-pointer-to-void/36646099