# How to use g_signal_handlers_block_by_func()

Tags: c, gtk3

I listen to "changed" signal of a `GtkComboBox`. I empty and refill `GtkComboBoxText` which is a simple variant of `GtkComboBox`. I'm trying to use a macro `g_signal_handlers_block_by_func(instance, func, data)` so that the "changed" signal won't be emitted to my callback function while emptying and refilling that box.

I get an error when passing a function as a func: error: ISO C forbids passing argument 6 of ‘g_signal_handlers_block_matched’ between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Werror=pedantic]

It happens because func is casted to `gpointer` (typedef to `(void*))` in `g_signal_handlers_block_matched`. As I have understood casting function pointer to data pointer is illegal.

Example:

```
static void my_callback(GtkComboBox *box, GtkComboBox *other_box)
{
  // Some code here
}


g_signal_connect(combo_box, "changed", G_CALLBACK(my_callback), other_box);

// To temporary block changed signals for reaching other_box:
g_signal_handlers_block_by_func(combo_box, G_CALLBACK(my_callback), other_box);
```

Also tried without G_CALLBACK but it doesn't make a difference. The issue is the same.

How should I use `g_signal_handlers_block_by_func`?

Comment: Show your actual code, specifically how you are calling `g_signal_handlers_block_by_func()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GObject and GLib require a compiler that "does the right thing" when casting function pointers to `void*` and vice versa.

From the [build code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/meson.build#L369-371) and [GLib wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GLib/CompilerRequirements#Function_pointer_conversions):

> GLib heavily relies on the ability to convert a function pointer to a `void*` and back again losslessly. Any platform or compiler which doesn’t support this cannot be used to compile GLib or code which uses GLib. This precludes use of the `-pedantic` GCC flag with GLib.

Comment: Why can't it use another function pointer for that? Eg. `void (*)(void)` ? Or why not use an union that can hold `void*` and `void (*)(void)`? Based on`answeres [why-cant-i-cast-a-function-pointer-to-void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645660/why-cant-i-cast-a-function-pointer-to-void) and [c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer)

Comment: This is presumably not the only place in GObject that requires that functionality.